# GroupBy with linq entity poco

Tags: c#, list, linq, group-by

I have this entities

```
public class Counter
    {
        public int DocEntry { get; set; }
        public int LineId { get; set; }
        public string Item { get; set; }
        public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
        public string FromWarehouse { get; set; }
        public string ToWarehouse { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Batch> batchs { get; set; }
    }

    public class Batch
    {
      public string BatchNumber { get; set; }

        public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
    }
```

And I have List count,I should group the elements of the list based on the Item value, FromWarehouse, ToWarehouse, and the result should be grouped with summed quantity and the list of Batch merged, I tried cycling the Counter list using the foreach method and inserting in a new list the first element, in the subsequent iterations if the current row reflected the values of the one already in the list I summarized the quantities and added to the Batch list the elements of the Batch list of the i-th line, otherwise I added a new line, this approach I it seemed too complicated, not being very expert on linq or in any case is there an easier way to manage the group by?

This is my method:

```
public static List<Counter> GroupBy(List<Counter> list)
        {
            List<Counter> rows = new List<Counter>();
            int i = 0;
            foreach (Counter elem in list)
            {
                if (list.First() == elem)
                {
                    rows.Add(elem);
                    i++;
                }
                else
                {

                    if (elem.Item == rows.ElementAt(i).Item &&
                        elem.FromWarehouse == rows.ElementAt(i).FromWarehouse &&
                        elem.ToWarehouse == rows.ElementAt(i).ToWarehouse)
                    {
                        rows.First().Quantity += elem.Quantity;
                        rows.First().batchs.Add(elem.batchs.First());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        rows.Add(elem);
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }

            return rows;
        }
```

***This is the solution:***

```
public static List<Counter> GroupBy(List<Counter> list)
        {
            List<Counter> rows = new List<Counter>();

            foreach (Counter elem in list)
            {
                if (rows.Any(x=>x.Item == elem.Item &&
                        x.FromWarehouse == elem.FromWarehouse &&
                        x.ToWarehouse == elem.ToWarehouse))
                {
                    rows.First().Quantity += elem.Quantity;
                    rows.First().batchs.Add(elem.batchs.First());
                }
                else
                {
                    rows.Add(elem);
                }
            }

            return rows;
        }
```

Comment: What did you tried?

Comment: I just edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to write the *Linq*, step by step.

"I have List `count`":

```
   List<Counter> count = ...
```

"I should *group* the elements of the list based on the `Item` value, `FromWarehouse`, `ToWarehouse`":

```
   var result = count
     .GroupBy(item => new {
        item.Item,
        item.FromWarehouse
        item.ToWarehouse 
      })
```

"`result` should be grouped with *summed* `quantity` and the list of `Batch` *merged*", i.e. you should `Aggregate` items within *each* `chunk`

```
   var result = count  
     .GroupBy(item => new {
        item.Item,
        item.FromWarehouse
        item.ToWarehouse 
      })
     .Select(chunk => new {
        key = chunk.Key,
        summary = chunk.Aggregate(
          Tuple.Create(0m, new List<Batch>()),                      // initial empty
          (s, a) => Tuple.Create(s.Item1 + a.Quantity,              // add
                                 s.Item2.Concat(a.batchs).ToList()) // merge
      })
```

Finally, let's represent the `result` in more convenient (readable) format:

```
   var result = count  
     .GroupBy(item => new {
        item.Item,
        item.FromWarehouse
        item.ToWarehouse 
      })
     .Select(chunk => new {
        key = chunk.Key,
        summary = chunk.Aggregate(
          Tuple.Create(0m, new List<Batch>()),
          (s, a) => Tuple.Create(s.Item1 + a.Quantity, 
                                 s.Item2.Concat(a.batchs).ToList())
      })
     .Select(item => new {
        Item = item.key.Item,
        FromWarehouse = item.key.FromWarehouse,
        ToWarehouse = item.key.ToWarehouse,
        Quantity = item.summary.Item1,
        Batches = item.summary.Item2
      }); // Add ToArray() if you want to materialize
```